# C: Finding duplicate string values in a file

Tags: c, string, file, qsort

So I have a file containing lets say:

```
cat
dog
cat
```

I am trying to go through the file, have it recognize there are two `cat` elements and one `dog` element, and then have in the same file edited as:

```
cat - 2
dog - 1
```

I already have all the words saved in an array of strings, `char **wordList`, and I am trying to sort them with qsort and then put it in the format as described above. My qsort functions are:

```
stringcmp(const void *a, const void *b)
 {
     const char **ia = (const char **)a;
     const char **ib = (const char **)b;
     return strcmp(*ia, *ib);
 }

 void wordSort(char **wordlist)
 {
     size_t strings_len = numwords - 1;
     qsort(wordlist, strings_len, sizeof(char*), stringcmp);
     wordFile(wordlist);
 }

void wordFile(char **wordlist)
 {
     if((outFilePtr2 = fopen(outWords, "w")) != NULL)
     {
         for(x = 1; x < numwords; x++)
         {
             fputs(wordlist[x], outFilePtr2);
             fputs("\n", outFilePtr2);
         }
         fclose(outFilePtr2);
     }
     else
     {
         printf("File\"%s\" could not be opened.\n", outWords);
     }
 }
```

It is not sorting anything in order though. How do I fix it?

Comment: Perhaps `wordList` is not properly allocated?  Suggest posting that code.

Comment: On most machines, `sizeof(wordlist) == sizeof(char*)`. Don't use `sizeof` to find the size of an allocation.

Comment: `wordlist` works perfectly because I have it going into a file right now just not sorted.

Comment: What is the value of `strings_len`?

Comment: In this particular case I have 98 strings stored in `char **wordlist`

Comment: But after `size_t strings_len = sizeof(wordlist)/sizeof(char*);`, `string_len == 1`. C does not work like you think it does.

Comment: How do I fix it then?

Comment: Two ways: One: put a sentinel value at the end of the array (likely `NULL`), and iterate though the array until you find it. Two: Pass the size of the array as a second argument to `void wordSort(char **, size_t)`.

Comment: I'm still getting nothing from it. I have the right size, but it isn't sorting.

Comment: Post more code. Also, for modern C `stringcmp()` should really be `int stringcmp()`.

Comment: I included my `wordFile` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following program works with your definition of stringcmp (which seems correct):

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    qsort(argv, argc, sizeof(char *), &stringcmp);
    for (i = 0; i != argc; i++) printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
}
```

Thus I suspect that you have a problem with the definition of `char **wordList`.

**UPDATE**

This version slightly modified/completed version of your program works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *outWords = "outWords.txt";
char *wordList[] = { "cat", "dog", "cat" };
#define numwords (sizeof(wordList) / sizeof(wordList[0]))
FILE *outFilePtr2;
int x;

int stringcmp(const void *a, const void *b)
 {
     const char **ia = (const char **)a;
     const char **ib = (const char **)b;
     return strcmp(*ia, *ib);
 }       

 void wordSort(char **wordlist)
 {       
     qsort(wordlist, numwords, sizeof(char*), stringcmp);
     wordFile(wordlist);
 }   

void wordFile(char **wordlist)
 {   
     if((outFilePtr2 = fopen(outWords, "w")) != NULL)
     {
         for(x = 0; x < numwords; x++)
         { 
             fputs(wordlist[x], outFilePtr2);
             fputs("\n", outFilePtr2);
         }
         fclose(outFilePtr2);
     }
     else
     {
         printf("File\"%s\" could not be opened.\n", outWords);
     }
 }

int main() {
    wordSort(wordList);
    wordFile(wordList); 
    return 0;
}
```

I adapted the second argument of `qsort` (else the last string pointer would not be considered, and left unchanged). I also adapted the initialization `x=0` of the `for`-loop in `wordFile` for the first string to be printed, too.

You may have defined **wordList in some other way causing a problem, you did not provide the code for it.